# Netfilter: reading application level content?

Tags: c, linux, module, tcp, netfilter

I've been trying to read the packet content when implementing netfiler hooks.

I can correctly filter on IP fields or TCP fields, however, out of curiosity i've been trying to go further and also display the content of the application level payload, which fails.

I know as a principle that "firewalls operate at level 3", so in a way this is normal.

My question is: on the technical aspect, why is it that the sock_buffer seems to stop at the TCP/UDP header ?

This gets the IP header:

```
ip_header = (struct iphdr*)skb_network_header(sock_buff);
```

This gets the TCP header:

```
tcp_header = (struct tcphdr*)((char*)ip_header + sizeof(struct iphdr));
```

But if I then do this:

```
(char*) (tcp_header + 4*(tcp_header->doff))       //4*(tcp_header->doff) is size of tcp header
```

and display,I see with basic tests (for instance netcats to send 'AAAA') that it doesn't show those characters at all.

My second question then is: how can I access the rest of my packet at Linux modules level ?

EDIT:

Tried Joachim's suggestion but doesn't work either !

```
print_payload(tcp_header + 4*(tcp_header->doff));
```

with print_payload being:

```
    void print_payload(void *s){

        char *payload;
        int i;
        payload = s;

        for(i=0;i<8;i++){

            printk(KERN_INFO "%.2x|", payload[i]);

        }

        printk(KERN_INFO "\n");
    }
```

and it displays weird things like:

77|
70|
21|
ffffffc1|
00|
00|
00|
00|

once i start sending 'Z' characters through netcat...

Answer (score 1):

It's because you should do `(char*) tcp_header + 4*(tcp_header->doff)` (i.e. drop the parentheses around the addition).

The above expression type-casts `tcp_header` to a `char*` and adds an offset of `4*(tcp_header->doff)` bytes.

Your code adds an offset of `4*(tcp_header->doff) * sizeof(*tcp_header)` bytes to the pointer and then type-casts the resulting pointer to `char*`.